# iextendedentityproperties and storing NBT player data

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I totally don't understand `IExtendedEntityProperties` in Forge. What I want is to make some custom variables for players that will be stored somewhere (NBT). And, the way I've googled this told to use `IExtendedEntityProperties` feature. Here's the code.

PlayerProps.class

```
public class PlayerProps implements IExtendedEntityProperties {

public final static String compoundName = "playerProps";

protected EntityPlayer propsPlayer;
protected World parWorld;

protected String testString;

@Override
public void saveNBTData(NBTTagCompound parCompound) {
    NBTTagCompound compound = new NBTTagCompound();
    parCompound.setTag(compoundName, compound);
    
    compound.setString("testPar", testString);
}

@Override
public void loadNBTData(NBTTagCompound parCompound) {
    NBTTagCompound compound = new NBTTagCompound();
    compound.getTag(compoundName);
    
    testString = compound.getString("testPar");
}

@Override
public void init(Entity entity, World world) {
    propsPlayer = (EntityPlayer)entity;
    parWorld = world;
}

public String getTestString() {
    return testString;
}

public void setTestString(String string) {
    testString = string;
}

@SubscribeEvent
public void onEntityConstructing(EntityConstructing event) {
    
    if (event.entity instanceof EntityPlayer)
    {
        event.entity.registerExtendedProperties("PlayerProps", new PlayerProps());
    }
    
    
}

}
```

For test I'm using two test blocks - while sneak-rightclicking on one it must read string variable, on another - send it in chat

```
 public boolean onBlockActivated(World world,  int par2, int par3, int par4, 
        EntityPlayer player, int par6, float par7, float par8, float par9) {
        PlayerProps props = new PlayerProps();
    if (player.isSneaking()) {
                player.addChatMessage(new ChatComponentText(props.getTestString()));
        
        return true;
    }
    
    return false;
} 



     public boolean onBlockActivated(World world,  int par2, int par3, int par4, 
        EntityPlayer player, int par6, float par7, float par8, float par9) {
        PlayerProps props = new PlayerProps();
    if (player.isSneaking()) {
            props.setTestString("It Works!");
        
        return true;
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

And it always says null.

Comment: remove the comment when you implement the method: // TODO Auto-generated method stub

Answer (score 0):

You defined a constant String, so use it, it would avoid case problem ;)

```
public final static String compoundName = "playerProps";
```

See in the method `onEntityConstructing`:

```
event.entity.registerExtendedProperties("PlayerProps", new PlayerProps());
```

By the way, define also a constant for your property.

Comment: I've checked player's save using NBTExplorer - and haven't found any custom entry. I'm still don't completely understand the basic things about entitydata I guess =(